# Define member in class, but actual type not known till run time

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

This is probably a basic question for a regular C++ user. Functionally, I have an ECG monitor, and want to choose which output format to use at runtime. I have set up two classes that expose the same methods and members (ECGRecordingDefaultFormat and ECGRecordingEDFFormat) eg. ->InsertMeasure, ->setFrequency, ->setPatientName etc.

I know I could define one instance of each format class type, then put in:

```
if (ECGFormatToUse == ECGFormat.EDF) {
    ecgDefaultFormat.InsertMeasure(x);
}
if (ECGFormatToUse == ECGFormat.Default) {
    ecgEDFFormat.InsertMeasure(x);
}
```

all throughout the code, but I think I might not be using C++'s dynamic typing to its full extent.

The question is: can I define just one variable in main(), and after choosing the format I want at runtime, have the code use the right class with its exposed 'InsertMeasure' method, avoiding a whole lot of if/else's throughout the code?

I'd be happy with just a reference to which aspect of inheritance/polymorphism (?) I should be using, and can google away the rest.

Thanks guys.

Pete

Comment: Thanks for the answers Luchian, Basile and hmjd. What I got out of it was: create a virtual method in a base class, inherit from this class. Ups!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) with C++'s polymorphism.

```
class Base
{
   virtual void InsertMeasure() = 0; //virtual pure, make the base class abstract
};

class ECGRecordingDefaultFormat : public Base
{
   virtual void InsertMeasure();
};

class ECGRecordingEDFFormat : public Base
{
   virtual void InsertMeasure();
};

class Factory
{
   static Base* create(ECGFormat format)
   {
      if ( format == ECGFormat.EDF )
         return new ECGRecordingEDFFormat;
      if ( format == ECGFormat.Default )
         return new ECGRecordingDefaultFormat;
      return NULL;
   }
};

int main()
{
   ECGFormat format;
   //set the format
   Base* ECGRecordingInstance = Factory::create(format);
   ECGRecordingInstance->InsertMeasure();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answered but I posted this as I had it written:

```
class EcgFormat
{
public:
    virtual void InsertMeasure(int x) = 0;
};


class EcgFormatA : public EcgFormat
{
public:
    void InsertMeasure(int x)
    {
        cout << "EcgFormatA: " << x << "\n";
    }
};

class EcgFormatB : public EcgFormat
{
public:
    void InsertMeasure(int x)
    {
        cout << "EcgFormatB: " << x << "\n";
    }
};

class EcgFormatFactory
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<EcgFormat> makeEcgFormat(char a_format)
    {
        switch (a_format)
        {
        case 'A':
            return std::make_shared<EcgFormatA>();
            break;
        case 'B':
            return std::make_shared<EcgFormatB>();
            break;
        default:
            throw std::exception("Invalid format");
            break;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<EcgFormat> format = EcgFormatFactory::makeEcgFormat('A');
    format->InsertMeasure(5);

    return 0;
}
```

(I know this pretty much the same as @Luchian answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have an abstract super class `EcgFormat` (with several `virtual` methods kept abstract with `=0`) and several sub-classes `ECGRecordingDefaultFormat`, `ECGRecordingEDFFormat` etc